# JavaScript: Firefox addon panel is empty/blank

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, panel

Javascript noob here.

I'm following the Firefox [Annotator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/annotator/index.html) add-on tutorial and using the online Add-on Builder. I'm coming up against a very basic and odd problem: every panel I make is empty (i.e. there is no textarea displayed):

[image: Empty FF panel]

I tried to simplify my code as much as possible in order to flesh out the issue, but I still have the problem with the below code:

```
exports.main = function() {
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width: 180,
    height: 180,
    contentUrl: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jetpack&useformat=mobile"
});
panel.show();
};
```

I'm on Mac with FF20. Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit**:
I can't load it in safe mode, but I've tried disabling all other plugins and doing a reset, and still don't see any improvement.

Comment: It's spelled `contentURL`, not `contentUrl`.

Comment: Haha, you're the man. Thanks. I hope this remains the stupidest question I ask on stackoverflow. Post it as an answer if you like.